# Edit UITableViewCell property on scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am making an app in which there are quotes from famous people in an array which are being read out by `openears` and a `tableView` which shows all the quotes. The currently reading quote is to be displayed in the tableview in a different color than the other quotes. I tried with the following function in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but the color of the cell remains the same unless the user scrolls it out and then come back to the view. But I need to set the color automatically and at the same time all other cells should revert back to the initial(white) color. Is there any method which can achieve this? I don't want to reload the table each time to achieve this.

```
if ([[arrayOfQuoteIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]intValue] == currentQuoteId) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"D3FFFF"];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"D3FFFF"];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"D3FFFF"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"D3FFFF"];
        cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"D3FFFF"];
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can be wrong but how You want to achieve change of cell appearence without redrawing cell?

If You don't want reload all table try to reload just changed rows

`- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`